# Margin ignored by LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, margin

I'm creating dynamically views containing a `LinearLayout` and add them to an outer `LinearLayout`. I would like to set a margin around the created views, but the `layout_margin` in the XML file is ignored. It works, if I set the parameters in the code, but I would like to specify the margin in the layout XML.

Setting the margin in the XML layout will be ignored:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Setting the margin while creating is honored:

```
LinearLayout productView = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.product_preview, null);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);  
productView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This is the outer layout. The views are added to `dealer_activity_product_list`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dealer_activity_dealer_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/dealer_activity_dealer_image_desc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dealer_activity_dealer_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dealer_activity_product_list1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dealer_activity_product_list2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried using Hierarchy viewer? or tried dumping the view to uiautomator? With these tools you can inspect your layouts. Can you post the full code you are using?

Comment: could you please post more code? Like complete XML? I think that you set margin to wrong item

Comment: I used HierachyViewer to inspect the layout. While setting the margin in code is reflected in the attributes of the layout I can't find the values set in the XML file.

Comment: I added the outer layout to the question ...

Comment: I've got the same problem, if I add a parent linear layout outside the layout with margin in the xml file it works. Eclipse claims the extra linear layout is useless, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the attribute for the *inner* LinearLayout or the *containing* LinearLayout?
At least, the following does work inside a LinearLayout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/xxx"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    />
```

Comment: I'm sure that the author sets margin for outer layout.    
xmlns attribute is only appliable to root elements

Comment: I'm setting the attribute for a `LinearLayout` that is contained by another `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score -1):

There is a common "nested layouts" pattern.
That is, you create an auxiliary container layout and achieve the desired effect positioning the internal layout within the container layout.

Sort of:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        ...
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        >
    ...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is it one single layout or two nested layouts that you add programmatically to the outer layout?

Comment: I mean, I can believe that `android:layout_margin` is ignored for the layout that is the root of the XML, but I would not expect that `android:layout_margin` worked normally for internal layouts (please check if it does in your environment), unless the parent of this internal layout was added programmatically to its parent.

Answer (score -2):

set `padding` instead of `layout_margin` in outer view.

Hope it will work

Comment: This would set a space around all views contained in the outer view, but not in between the contained views.